# How To Change Apex Class into a Scheduable Apex Class

Tags: class, scheduled-apex

I am still a beginner and I trying to create a trigger that will create a task on a weekly basis (task once a week) until a field in the opportunity is label complete. This Trigger and Class work, as well as 100% Code Coverage, but I know this isn't how you create a class that can be scheduable. Where do I go from there?

Thank You!

//Trigger:

```
trigger Opportunitytask on Opportunity (after insert, after update){
  List<Task> carry=new List<Task>();
  for(Opportunity opp:trigger.new)
  {
    if(opp.PM__c!=null && opp.PM_close_Out_Checklist__c!='complete')
     {
        task t=new task();
        t.whatid=opp.id;
        t.ownerid=opp.PM__c;
        t.subject='Email BDM Weekly Update';
        t.priority='Normal';
        t.status='Not Started';
        carry.add(t);
     }

     insert carry;

  }
}
```

//Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestOpportunitytask {

static testMethod void insertTask() {

        Test.StartTest();
        Account acc = new account();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        acc.Industry = 'Healthcare';

        insert acc;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
         opp.Name = 'Test Opportunity'; 
        opp.CloseDate = System.today();
        opp.StageName = 'Proposal';
        opp.Type = 'Repeat Business - Wrkforce HC';
        opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        opp.PM__c=null;
        insert opp;

        opp.PM__c='005U0000004Y1wf';

        update opp;

        Task t=new Task();

        t.whatid='006U000000QS6x5';
        t.ownerid='005U0000004Y1wf';
        t.Subject='Email BDM Weekly Update';
        t.priority='Normal';
        t.status='Not Started';

        insert t;

        System.assertEquals('006U000000QS6x5',t.whatid);

              Test.StopTest();
     }
    }
```

Comment: You have couple of bad coding practices:
1- never hard code IDs 
2- try to avoid DML inside for loops especially in triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scheduled class should be something like this:

(The below code is not guaranteed to run, I wrote that pretty fast)

Note: you can play with the params of `Schedule()` method to set the running of the scheduled job.

```
global class ProcessOpportunityTask implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable  {


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id , PM__c
                                         FROM Opportunity  
                                         PM__c!=null 
                                         && 
                                         PM_close_Out_Checklist__c <> 'complete' ]);
    }

    global static void Schedule(string sch) {
        ProcessOpportunityTask a = new ProcessOpportunityTask();
        if (String.isBlank(sch))
            sch = '0 0 01 * * ?'; // defaults to 1am every day
        System.schedule('ProcessOpportunityTask', sch, a);
    }   

    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)  {
       ProcessOpportunityTask n = new ProcessOpportunityTask();
       Database.executeBatch(n,1);
    } 

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

         List<Task> carry=new List<Task>();
        for(sobject s : scope) {
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)s;

            task t=new task();
            t.whatid=opp.id;
            t.ownerid=opp.PM__c;
            t.subject='Email BDM Weekly Update';
            t.priority='Normal';
            t.status='Not Started';
            carry.add(t);
        }      
        Insert carry;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }


}
```

Comment: (1) why scope size = 1? (2) Missing declaration of `carry`; as an aside .... (3)  `global` could be `public` and (4) `Schedule` method most useful when called by Apex. If class is scheduled from UI, then not required

Comment: 1-  just a sample code, he can set the scope to any size
2- carry is declared inside the execute function
3- you are right
4- true